# Помогите найти проблему зацикливания коннекта PHP к базе данных Sybase

Tags: php, sql, apache, sybase

смотрю `netstat` - пишет до 1000 штук подобных строк:

> tcp 0 0 localhost.localdomain:48702 localhost.lo:sybaseanywhere TIME_WAIT

так же много в `netstat` подобных коннектов

> tcp 0 0 WebDB2008:47295 WebDB2008:sybaseanywhere TIME_WAIT

база данных в это время постоянно пишет в лог подобное:

> TCP/IP: Received connection request from 127.0.0.1:48702.
>   Connection from 127.0.0.1:48702 assigned connection ID 16808

не могу найти скрипт, в котором идет это зацикливание. Сайт очень большой и серьезный - нет возможности просмотреть все *php*-файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Если точек с коннеком к базе (т.е. вызовов `mysqli_connect` или `new mysqli(...)`) не много, то попробуйте воспользоваться XDebug`ом. Ставите на коннекты точки останова, открываете страниц сайта, и начиная со второго коннекта смотрите стэктрэйс. Он и подскажет вам где искать зацикливание.

Comment: поставил xdebug но не могу теперь правильно настроить remote и trace что бы отловить ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй закрывать коннект или подключать скрипт при помощи

```
require_once('connect.php');
```

И закрывай соединение при помощи функции

```
mysqli_close()
```

Comment: Все как раз подключено через require_once и подгружается класс, в котором и конструктор присутствует и корректный деструктор с дисконектом, который в свою очередь вызывается в конце вызывающего файла. т.е. disconnect тоже есть.